# BeautifulSoup - Extract text with tags as text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Lets say i have the html

```
<div>Hey</div><div>This is <b>some text<b/>, right here. <a>Link<a/></div>
```

and the code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

print() will return

```
['Hey', 'This is ', 'some text', ', right here.', 'Link']
```

for texts.

How could I exclude tags like 'b' (that only contain text), so I could get the desired output which is

```
['Hey', 'This is <b>some text<b/>, right here.', 'Link']
```

Also preferably **not** strings but equivalent NavigableStrings or similar.

In other words, how can I exclude some tags from navigating the tree?

Comment: What do you mean by *How could I exclude tags like 'b' (that only contain text),* what are other tags you consider to be like b?

Comment: Only 'i' and possibly br, although my html only contains b. I basically want to extract all text resources from tags separately except for 'b' for which I want to extract the text of the parent excluding any text from other sibling tags.

Comment: Can you add a more complex example and what you want as output?

Comment: Affirmative. I updated the question. Hopefully It's complex enough. There's an assumption b won't have nested tags (ie. "only text").

Answer (score -1):

based on updated OP's question:

```
eDiv = soup.findAll("div")
if eDiv.find("b") is None:
    tag = eDiv.text
else:
    tag = eDiv
```

now you can append this into list.

Comment: Would work on my example, but a different approach is needed on my actual html. Some divs contain other elements that I want to extract text from separately. My html is bigger and I cant manually pick out the elements. Some tags that contain text are h1, h2, p, li, a etc... and divs, but some divs have other elements inside.

Comment: there must be some unique identifier of div you are interested in, and then you can use CSS selector(using soup.select) to get those. if you give large chunk of html here, I may try to get that unique identifier for you.

Comment: `eDiv = soup.findAll("div")
if eDiv.find("b") is None:
 tag = eDiv.text
else:
 tag = eDiv`  now you can append this into list.